# How to find the program i made

Tags: windows, file

I can't find the program i made as in find i mean find without the IDE Visual Studio Express 2010

Comment: Do you mean you can't find the .exe of the program generated? If so, it will be under the bin\Debug or bin\Release folder depending on your build. A bit more explanation would help.

Comment: I found the application under bin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In visual studio, click on your project in the solution explorer.

You should see the path to your project file (csproj or vbproj).

Open this folder in Windows Explorer, then open bin/debug or bin/release, depending on your build configuration (debug by default).

Answer (score 1):

Look in the  bin\debug folder under your project directory.

Comment: it is bin\Debug not debug\bin